# Node js : spawn throws error in linux

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

The following is my code, It works in windows with out error but when I setup my project in server (linux) it is  not working and throws error

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
   javaCmd= spawn('java', ['-cp',__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/dom4j.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/poi-3.9-20121203.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/poi-ooxml-3.9.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/xmlbeans-2.5.0.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/xmlbeans-xmlpublic-2.6.0.jar;'+__dirname+'/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/lib/excelreader.jar',  'astral.excelreader.Main', catid, id,target_path]);


 javaCmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

        console.log(data);
  });
 javaCmd.stdout.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log(code);
  });
 javaCmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {

        console.log(data);
  });
```

Following is the error

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

Anybody know its reason? I did n't set any other path for java. I tried to set using `$ vi ~/.bash_profile` but I got the following response

```
-bash: $: command not found
```

Anybody know how to set path in linux server

Comment: Try with this `spawn('/Java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java', [])`

Comment: Try putting a try catch block around the code that is failing so you can catch and output the error.  That should give you more information to help figure out what the error actually is.

Comment: Also, if you do a quick search on stack overflow on "node.js spawn enoent" you will find most people having path issues, I would bet your problem will be the same.

Comment: @damphat not working, do you know how to set java path in linux

Comment: When you convert your app from Windows to Linux most probable bugs that will be encountered are related to the file system being case sensitive.

Comment: You can also catch process errors more elegantly with `javaCmd.on('error', function(e){console.error(e)});`. It will only provide the same information as the exception message but allows you handle it without it crashing your app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944890/fatal-error-unable-to-find-package-java-lang-in-classpath-or-bootclasspath)