# Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

Tags: java, node.js, node-java

i am trying to use node-java package.i need to run small java code from node.js.first i run command

```
npm install java
```

after that i cloned source code of this library.(https://github.com/joeferner/node-java)
i went to node-java directory using

```
cd node-java
```

then run command ./compile-java-code.sh and getting error

Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath

i am using ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. when i run command

```
java -version
```

its returning

```
java version "1.7.0_75"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.4) (7u75-2.5.4-1~precise1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.75-b04, mixed mode)
```

and when i run command `javac -version` its returning

```
javac 1.7.0_75
```

perhaps its require some additional environment configuration.How to handle this issue.Please guideline.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the script to compile node-java I see the setting for bootclasspath there:
`-bootclasspath /opt/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar`

Do you have this jar file `/opt/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar`? If not, then you may want to adjust the script to point to your JRE location.