# Package does not exist error when package was added to classpath

Tags: java

Note, linked solutions (ex. [Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath or bootclasspath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944890/fatal-error-unable-to-find-package-java-lang-in-classpath-or-bootclasspath)) do not work.

I get this error, but the package is imported (commons... .jar)

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple //does not exist import
org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutableTriple
```

Source code

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.MutableTriple;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Triple;
```

Build code:

> export
>   JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
>   -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -classpath \ "../lib/commons-lang3-3.4.jar;../lib/httpclient-4.5.jar;../lib/httpcore-4.4.1.jar;../lib/org.json-20120521.jar;../lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.0-20150606.170503-1383.jar;../src/:../lib/commons-lang3-3.4-javadoc.jar;../lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.0-20150606.170503-1383-sources.jar" \   -d output \    ../src/com/tymaf/pdf/*.java

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Could you please format your question correctly? Why do you have a backslash between -classpath and the rest of the command? Why do you have quotes around the classpath? From which directory do you execute that command, and what is the directory layout?

Comment: how are you importing the external library to your project? what process you did.
Your questions is very ambiguous so please make it clear.

Comment: it would be helpful to format the 'build code'. This seem to be multiple commands in sequence and the many `\\` are probably line joiners that can be removed here for better readability.

Comment: @user1122069 "Technically I got that from the other answer." This shows that I cared about your question and spend some time to give you the hole picture of solving it. but it seems you do not appreciate that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check your classpath. Looks like you mixed delimiters `;` and `:`.

Also instead of including `jar` with compiled classes (library itself). You've included `java-docs` and `sources` that are useless in classpath.

```
../src/:
../lib/commons-lang3-3.4-javadoc.jar;
../lib/pdfbox-app-2.0.0-20150606.170503-1383-sources.jar
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my suggestion**

### How to compile and use `.jar` extension

`.jar` extension can be imported different ways depending on your environment and IDE.

Here how it work as native mode from console.

1. Download the `.jar.zip` library from 
   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/Downloadcommonslang333jar.htm
2. Create a folder in your working (project) directory call it `libs`
3. Unzip the downloaded file and copy `commons-lang3-3.3.jar` to your working directory `libs`
4. I have also created a class just for testing call it `TheNewWork.java` and added the 3 imports.
5. Now from your working directory `c:\projects` for Compile:

   `javac -classpath "/Projects/libs/commons-lang3-3.3.jar;" TheNewWork.java`
6. And for running it:

   `java -classpath "/Projects/libs/commons-lang3-3.3.jar;" TheNewWork`

If you have more than one `.jar` just add `;` for Windows and `:` for Linux. Btw I use windows 10 cmder console and java jdk1.8.0_66. In other OS console you might need to put `.:Projects...etc` in stead of `/Projects...etc`. but the idea is the same.

**UPDATE** 
In windows it is possible to set classpath like

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Projects\libs\commons-lang3-3.3.jar
```

OR in Linux

```
export CLASSPATH=".:/Projects/libs/commons-lang3-3.3.jar"
```

Then you can run `javac TheNewWork.java` but it is personal taste to do it this or the other way. Some things similar is also possible to do in other OS.

Last thing, if you lazy and do neither want to write a full command line nor create a classpath, you could create a batch file with the full command line and run it that way in stead ;)

Some references:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html
- https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html
- https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-classpath-Windows.asp

I hope this solves your problem

**Before the solution**
[image]

**After the solution**
[image]

---

**NOTE** 
In addition thanks to @MarkPeters notified me on my previous answer: Adding application dependencies directly to the JRE libs is not a good approach, as it makes the JRE suitable for running only one Java application, rather than being a generic runtime. Plus it would complicate whatever deployment the OP wants to do. lib/ext is made for extending the core Java APIs, as described here: [docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/install.html). Not for normal application dependencies.